# How to use window.caches to save pages from window object?

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

Most examples of saving an 'app shell' show the process from a service worker. However I noticed that you can also access the caches object from the window.

So my question is, can I save pages for offline from the a page itself, and if so, what is the point of a service worker if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a chicken-and-the-egg problem here: while your web pages can read from and write to the same caches that a service worker has access to, via `window.caches`, you need a service worker to intercept the initial navigation request for a web page in order to respond to it using the cache.

In other words, using `window.caches` presupposes that your page is already loaded, so it doesn't help you load the page while offline.