# Using the Cache API to cache Web pages without Service Workers

Tags: javascript, html, caching, service-worker

I'm using the [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) and I'm exploring how much I can do with it without having to use Service Workers.

I have two main use cases:

1. Loading cached assets when the user is offline
2. Reloading the page when the user is offline

---

For the first use case, I can cache images using the following code:

```
if('caches' in window) {
  caches.open('my-cache').then(function(cache_obj) { 
    cache_obj.addAll(['/', '/img/first.png', '/img/second.png'])
      .then(function() { 
        console.log('Cached!');
      });
  });
}
```

When I take the user offline, then I load the image into the DOM programmatically like so:

```
$('body').append('<img src="/img/first.png">');
```

The image appears on the page as expected. If I take out `first.png` from the list of cached images, and then repeat this, the image does not appear [because it is not cached]. So the Cache API works quite nicely for the first use case.

However, I'm wondering if I can do the same thing for the second use case. Can I cache a full HTML page offline, and then have it reload when the user is offline, but without having to setup a service worker?

**Note**: I have a way I can do something very similar using localStorage/sessionStorage to cache the HTML content of the page and then intelligently load it into the current page when the user is offline [using offline.js detection], but I'm looking for a simpler approach using the Cache API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use window.caches to save pages from window object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239518/how-to-use-window-caches-to-save-pages-from-window-object)

Comment: @JeffPosnick Thanks. I guess this means the second use-case is not possible?

Comment: You need a service worker to handle the navigation request to a given page while offline.

Comment: @JeffPosnick Thanks. I really wished it worked differently

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

You can also read the property **navigator.onLine** [true/false]

When the connection is *offline*, the class is added to the **body**

The **Service Worker is not necessary** for this task

```
// We capture the events online - offline
// You can also: if (navigator.onLIne) {... }

window.addEventListener('online', function () {
  $('body').toggleClass('offline').append('<img src="/img/first.png">');
});
window.addEventListener('offline', function () {
  $('body').toggleClass('offline').append('<img src="/img/second.png">');
});
```